# Android Can't Get Cached Image From File Path

Tags: java, android, file, cordova, caching

We have a Cordova app. I am getting an Image passed to me which is saved in the cache.

I need to make a file from a string url:

```
File pictureFile = new File(fileURL)
```

However when I try to load that image file it keeps failing (file not found).

A sample of what I am passed is this:

```
file:///data/data/co.appname.app/cache/tfss-4cb94488-1843-4ad3-8d02-8802008c7186-1685720347.jpg
```

I have tried making the following urls and none work when I create a file

```
/data/data/co.appname.app/files/tfss-4cb94488-1843-4ad3-8d02-8802008c7186-1685720347.jpg

file:/data/data/co.appname.app/files/tfss-4cb94488-1843-4ad3-8d02-8802008c7186-1685720347.jpg
```

I also tried taking just the file name `tfss-4cb94488-1843-4ad3-8d02-8802008c7186-1685720347.jpg` and getting the cached directory directly and that didn't work either

```
String path = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + tfss-4cb94488-1843-4ad3-8d02-8802008c7186-1685720347.jpg
```

That just ends up with `/data/data/co.appname.app/files/tfss-4cb94488-1843-4ad3-8d02-8802008c7186-1685720347.jpg` which still comes up null.

The image HAS to exist there though because we are uploading it to Twitter and Cordova is saving the image in the cache.

Can you advise what the issue might be?

Answer (score 2):

I needed to call `getCacheDir()` not `getFilesDir()`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: This does answer the question and I am the author.